# Converting json object to xml

Tags: json, xml, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert my json object to xml using xml-js library and function json2xml. while i try to implement it i am getting an Error as

Error: Buffer is not defined

I am using Angular8.

Please refer to this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrju7j) for Reproducible error.

Please Guide me regarding this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.module defined this. this will set the Buffer into the global

```
(window as any).global = window;
declare var require: any;

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Buffer: any;
  }
}

window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;

@NgModule(...
```

then in your app.component.ts remove the argument in the xmlc because in your ts. you're not accepting any arguements.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. i am able to fix the buffer issue.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the buffer issue,

> npm i buffer

Add these in app.component.ts

```
import * as buffer from 'buffer'; 
(window as any).global.Buffer = buffer
```